# emacs/org-mode export accent acute

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Exporting from `.org` to `.md` (using either `ox-gfm` or normal markdown) org-mode adds unwanted backslashes (\) before each acute accent (`). So 
`path/file` becomes \`path/file\`.

Any idea how I can turn that off?

Thanks, F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backtick (grave accent) in Markdown is used to delimit code samples.

The equivalent in org-mode is the equal sign. For example, the following orgmode:

```
The file is at =/tmp/toto=
```

Exports as Markdown to:

```
The file is at `/tmp/toto`
```

If you want a backtick in Markdown, [you have to escape it](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash), and that is precisely what the org-mode exporter is doing.